# AST usage in search button of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to know how AST(Abstract Syntax Tree ) is used in the search button of eclipse.Can anyone provide me the link or some info about it .Help

Answer (score 1):

This is a small example for that:

```
 SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern(fTarget.getDeclaringType()
         .getFullyQualifiedName()
         + "." + fTarget.getElementName(), type, IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES,
         SearchPattern.R_PREFIX_MATCH | SearchPattern.R_ERASURE_MATCH);
 SearchEngine engine = new SearchEngine();
 engine.search(pattern, new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant() },
         scope, new SearchRequestor() {

             @Override public void acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch match) throws CoreException {
                 if (match.getAccuracy() == SearchMatch.A_ACCURATE && !match.isInsideDocComment()) {
                     invocations.add(match);
                 }
             }
         }, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1, SubProgressMonitor.SUPPRESS_SUBTASK_LABEL));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html) that I found:

> The Abstract Syntax Tree is the base
>   framework for many powerful tools of
>   the Eclipse IDE, including
>   refactoring, Quick Fix and Quick
>   Assist. The Abstract Syntax Tree maps
>   plain Java source code in a tree form.
>   This tree is more convenient and
>   reliable to analyse and modify
>   programmatically than text-based
>   source. This article shows how you can
>   use the Abstract Syntax Tree for your
>   own applications.